# Is our main site eligible for graduation and who has to take the decision of graduation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Currently, our main site is in the public beta stage and the next stage is the graduation of our main site.

With this context, I want to know whether our main site is eligible in all aspects to get a graduation.

If our main site is eligible to get graduation in all aspects then who has to take the decision of graduating the site?

Comment: I had already asked [a similar question](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551/2444) in the past. I looked at our statistics [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence), and they don't look perfect. In particular, I've noticed that the number of questions asked has decreased. I will talk to other more experienced moderators and ask them if they want to answer your question.

Comment: I updated the status because the Moderators have spoken to this in a separate post.  https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/artificial-intelligence-is-graduating-becoming-full-non-beta-site. The site will lose the Beta label on December 16th.